# Meaning of feet up

Tags: meaning-in-context

I don't get the meaning of feet up in the following sentence

> Why was it that birds should sing and bring joy to whole family, only
>   to end as a heap of feathers feet up, on the bottom of cage?

It would be helpful if you can explain the structure of the sentence 
Thanks in advance

Comment: [This](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/eb/dc/02/ebdc0227b2a10d24405f32e3d7023653.jpg) is the typical posture, feet up, of a dead bird.

Answer (score 1):

*"to end as a heap of feathers feet up, on the bottom of cage"* - basically means **to end up being dead**. **feet up** means *upside-down*.

This discussion [Why do animals turn upside-down when they die?](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/b7mzb/why_do_animals_turn_upsidedown_when_they_die/) may help you:

Comment: That thing was i was about to ask thanks alot . Interesting and creepy  at the same time